# My code overwrites data into one cell in excel if more than two users input their data

Tags: python, bots, telegram, openpyxl

Currently, I'm using pyTelegramBotAPI to make a bot. Everything worked well when it came to writing some input data from one user into the empty cell.

But the chaos started when more than two users used the bot at the same time. Their data literally was written over each others.

```
i = 1
name = message.text
al = ws_ishchi[f'F{i}'].value
while str(al) != "None":
    i += 1
    al = ws_ishchi[f'F{i}'].value
alo = ws_ishchi[f'F{i}']
alo.value = name
```

So as you see my code first finds an empty cell and only then starts writing data into it. But in a situation with two users when both of them sent the data in the same data it got ovewritten by each other.

Comment: The code is incomplete but you need to be aware that it is not possible to have two users working on the same XLSX file at the same time in a file system.

Comment: No. I couldn't explain you. I have a bot in Telegram which gets input data from USERS, but when two or more users work with a bot at the same time code chooses one cell in XLSX and stores only one USERS data overwriting another ones

Comment: Yep, concurrent access isn't possible.